# Creating a macro of mouse clicks

Tags: automated-tests, python-3.5

Is it possible to create an automated python script/macro for a series of mouse clicks? The goal is to open a webpage,  click button to open upload data window, and finally hit save button to crate a process.I am thinking of something equivalent to automated VBA macros which are recorded as operations are performed on sheets.

In past I have used `pyautogui` package for this activity but it requires hard coding of co-ordinates for mouse click and hence tedious to code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use **selenium** with python...

Check the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [examples](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage).

Any easy example would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

To download a file with firefox try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# To prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location

profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("http://www.drugcite.com/?q=ACTIMMUNE")

browser.find_element_by_id('exportpt').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('exporthlgt').click()
```

Another option would be the usage of **pythons webbrowser**.

[Automatetheboringstuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) gives some good examples.